# Converting links occuring inside a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am attempting to change a string occurance e.g. `http://www.bbc.co.uk/` so that it appears inside a html link e.g. `<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">http://www.bbc.co.uk</a>`

however for some reason my regex conversion does not work. Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

```
$text = "I love this website http://www.bbc.co.uk/";
$x = preg_replace("#[a-z]+://[^<>\s]+[[a-z0-9]/]#i", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $text);
var_dump($x);
```

outputs I love this website `http://www.bbc.co.uk/` (No html link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your weird character class is at fault:

```
 [[a-z0-9]/]
```

Double square brackets are for POSIX character classes like `[[:digit:]]`.

You meant to write just:

```
 [a-z0-9/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$x = preg_replace('#http://[?=&a-z0-9._/-]+#i', '<a target="_blank" href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you regex is giving you a match (in fact it's really not even close to giving you a match as you are not accepting periods in the domain name at all).  Try something like this:

```
$pattern = '#https?://.*\b#i';
$replace = '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>';
$x = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Note that I am not actually trying to validate the URL format here, so I just accept anything like http():// up to the next word boundary. It didn't seem as if you were going for a true URL validation regex anyway (i.e. validating there is at least one `.`, that the TLD component has 2-6 characters, etc.), so I just figure I would give you the simplest pattern that would match.